# jquery show image on row hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I have a list of records pulled from a database using PHP, displayed in a table.

Using jquery, on each row I want an image that only shows if the mouse is over the current row. The image is the same (its a delete icon).

I've got the image on each row already, but hidden with a `style="display: none;"` tag. it's just the hover business im stuck on.

How can i do this?

Answer (score -1):

something like:

```
$(yourTRSelection).hover(function(){
('yourImage', $(this)).show();
},function(){('yourImage', $(this)).hide();});
```

Comment: do i have to give each row and image a class yes?